# On Equivalence relations and partitions of a given set

Tags: calculus

Let $f: A \to B$ be a surjective function. Define a relation on $A$ by saying $a_0 \cong a_1$ if $f(a_0) = f(a_1)$. $A$ is then an equivalence relation obviously. If we define $C $ the set of all equivalence relations, then there is a bijection between $C$ and $B$.

#### Attempt

I was thinking to define a function $g : C \to A $ such that $g( [x] ) = x $ where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$. This function is bijective. Can we conlude that the composition $ f \circ g $ is a bijection between $B$ and $C$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $g$ is surjective since $f$ is, and that $g$ is injective since otherwise there would exist $a',a''\in A$ such that $[a']_f\neq [a'']_f$ but $f(a') = f(a'')$ which is of course impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a function $g$ that way. If $[x]=[y]$, but $x\neq y$, then $g([x])=x\neq y=g([y])$, but clearly it should be $g([x])=g([y])$. So $g$ is not well defined if $f$ is not an injection.